# Is there a listing of the video drivers in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, video, driver, lcd

I'm trying to pick an small (< 4") touchscreen TFT/LCD.  Because I'm no stranger to LCD/TFT linux driver development (I did one for an Epson chip), I'd rather pick one that is supported directly by the kernel.

**Is there a listing of the video chipsets that Linux natively supports?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`drivers/video/Kconfig`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.35/drivers/video/Kconfig#L245) file from the "Frame buffer hardware drivers" line onwards is probably the most up-to-date source.

Comment: "Read the source"  Thanks, Obi-Wan

Comment: +1 for the LXR link ... great site I've been using for years.